# How to fix the datetime in python?

Tags: python, datetime

I am getting an error message that says time data `2017-01-02 13:42:05.378582` does not match format `%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f`

```py
start_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(df['timestamp'].min(),'%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
end_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(df['timestamp'].max(),'%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
data_duration = (end_time - start_time).days

print(f"Number of unique users in experiment: {df['user_id'].nunique()}")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%y` is *year without century as a zero-padded decimal number* (`17`)

`%Y` is *year with century as a decimal number* (`2017`)

You need: `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'`